# Refresh page in the Controller without passing in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to be able to refresh the page after calling a method and passing `true` for the refresh parameter from the `Index` page. The function below, however, keeps redirecting me to the `SwitchMember()` function instead of the `Index` page. I simplified my code below.

Here is my call from the Index page (**Index.cshtml**):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchMember", new { memberId = 123, refresh = true })">Switch</a>
```

And here is the Controller action being called (**HomeController.cs**):

```
public ActionResult SwitchMember(int memberId, bool refresh)
{
    // do stuff here

    if(refresh) {
        // The problem with this is it keeps redirecting me to SwitchMember function
        // instead of the Index page
        return Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    return null;
}
```

**How do I make `SwitchMember()` a reusable function that refreshes the page where I called it from** instead of redirecting me to the action that I called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your return `Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);` to `return RedirectToAction("Index");`. Note that `SwitchMember` and `Index` actions should be in the same controller to use the `return RedirectToAction("Index");` but if they are in different controllers you can use `return RedirectToAction("Index", "<controller-name>");`

**UPDATE**

If you want to make the `SwitchMember` action reusable you can add additional parameter `string returnUrl` to your action `Index` (and the others) and pass the value `Request.Url.PathAndQuery`. Then in your controller you use `return Redirect(returnUrl)`. If you don't want to use the `returnUrl` parameter change your `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to `Request.Url.PathAndQuery`.

Comment: I'd like to be able to reuse the SwitchMember() function. So if I call it from the About page, it will redirect me to the About page, etc. That means I can't hardcode RedirectToAction("Index").

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your requirements. Can you give it a try? :)

Comment: Thanks! Yup, I removed the bool refresh parameter and replaced it with string returnUrl. Then do a refresh only if returnUrl is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the controller with something like:

```
 public ActionResult SwitchMember(int memberId, string refresh = null)
        {
            // do stuff here

            if (refresh != null)
            {
                // The problem with this is it keeps redirecting me to SwitchMember function
                // instead of the Index page
                return View(refresh);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And after use it in your pages like this:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("SwitchMember", new { memberId = 123, refresh = "About" })">Switch</a>
```

Note that you can also get current action, but i would not advise to use this approach because after you click that refresh, your current action will be *SwitchMember*.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchMember", new { memberId = 123, refresh = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() })">Switch</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just used Request.Url.AbsoluteUri instead of hardcoding "About", etc. I would accept this as an answer, but the other guy got to a solution first. Appreciate it, though!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned best solution for cases that needed to reusable actions which redirect to another actions and another actions don't have data model dependency to reusable is call the reusable and another action separately by client.

In your case call SwitchMember action by ajax call an in ajax success call index action. In this solution ,SwitchMember action will call by ajax because this action don't return any view.

**other solution have follow Disadvantages:**

-Using returnUrl:  Usually this is a security hole, unless parse url to controller and action and use RedirectToAction("controller","action");

[Preventing Open Redirection Attacks](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks)

-Using ReturnView : losing the ViewState of onother action.